# Selecting records in one table based on combinations of linked records in another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one table of facilities, identified by unique facility IDs. This is linked by facility_id to another table showing the multiple facility outputs, that is is the output table there are multiple records for each facility id, each record specifying a different output. I'd like to select all facilities with various combinations of outputs, ie all facilities with only output 1, or all with outputs 2 & 3.

Thanks

edit: 
ok, here we go. I have tblFacilities

```
facility_id   blahblah1   blahblah2   etc...
   1
   2
   3
   4
```

and tblOutputs

```
facility_id   output
   1          thermal
   1          electricity
   2          thermal
   3          electricity
```

I would like to be able to return records from tblFacilities for all facilities that: (1) have both thermal and electricity outputs; (2) have only thermal outputs. The tables are joined on facility_id, and facility_id has unique values in tblFacility.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried joining the tables?

Comment: yes, the tables are joined on facility_id

Comment: if you want one row back for each facilityID, you'll need to GROUP your output detail rows by one or more aggregate functions.  Can you show an example of your input rows and expected output?

Comment: hmm..yes, as soon as i figure out how to add a table...

Comment: you can just add one row for your facility and two or three rows for your output detail, then an example of what you'd like returned.

Comment: edited my answer again, you can use switch instead of case in access

Comment: Ok, i think its the last time i will edit my post, i forgot last time to add the query that sums all flags.. now it should be good .